# update data in a table from a FK referenced table

Tags: postgresql, insert

I have two tables `device_test_results` and `devices`.

```
device_test_results
- id
- device_id (FK)
- brand
- model
- serial_number

devices
- id
- brand
- model
- serial_number
```

`device_test_results` has a foreign key - `device_id` that references to the `devices` table

It's been a while since I've used this setup and there's plenty of data that references from `device_test_results` to `devices`.

I'm currently trying to get rid of this dependency so I added the `brand` `model` and `serial_number` columns in `device_test_results` to copy all of that existing information from the `devices` table and then remove this constraint so that these 2 tables become independent.

Any suggestions or places to look for a solution for this?

Comment: Why would you want to remove this dependency?  Keeping the device information in one place guarantees referential integrity -- i.e. that the values are correct.

Comment: I feel like using the devices table more like a configuration information for my script rather than a table that is referenced and now I can't change any information on it.
The device can still be referenced by the serial_number that is going to be saved in device_test_results, so if I really want to reference some information I can still do it, also I am saving all the necessary information I need in device_test_results anyways. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather try something like below. Get the required data using the `SELECT` query and `JOIN` with other table and then perform the `INSERT` operation accordingly.

```
INSERT INTO device_test_results (brand, model, serial_number) 
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT d.brand, d.model, d.serial_number 
from devices d 
inner join device_test_results dtr on dtr.device_id = d.id
) tab
```

**EDIT:**

Then use a `UPDATE` query doing a `JOIN` with other table like

```
UPDATE device_test_results AS dtr 
SET brand = d.brand
 model = d.model
 serial_number = d.serial_number
FROM devices AS d
WHERE dtr.device_id = d.id;
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, that worked but I just realized that I asked my question incorrectly. I need to update all the rows in the device_test_results with the referenced information from devices.
The insert statement simply adds new rows with all the information from devices table.